# Shared library dependencies - appropriate references and backward compatibility

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dll, shared-libraries

### Abstract

I have following taxonomy of assemblies (assemblies are signed and referenced with specific version restriction set to false):

```
C.dll  1.0
  |----A.dll  1.0
  |----B.dll  1.0

D.exe [works]
  |----A.dll  1.0   Type ->.
  |----B.dll  1.0          |
  |----C.dll  1.0          |
                           | type moved from A to B between versions
D.exe [issues?]            |
  |----A.dll  2.0          |
  |----B.dll  2.0   Type <-'
  |----C.dll  1.0
```

Is `D.exe` going to work?

### Actual problem

#### Introduction

I'm writing an assembly component, which can be used with ASP.NET MVC web applications. Such applications can vary, from those using old framework, e.g. System.Web.Mvc.dll 2.0, up to those using newest version, e.g System.Web.Mvc.dll 5.0.

The component itself uses `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` type - from System.Web.Mvc.dll, and `ModelClientValidationRule` type - in the past from System.Web.Mvc.dll (2.0, 3.0), then forwarded to System.Web.WebPages.dll 2.0.

#### Examples

- Now, if my component will be compiled using System.Web.Mvc.dll 4.0 and System.Web.WebPages.dll 2.0, and then referenced to web application, which runs on System.Web.Mvc.dll 3.0, compilation of web application will fail:

  > Error    30  Assembly 'MyComponent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  >   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
  >   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher
  >   version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,
  >   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
- On the other, if my component will be compiled using System.Web.Mvc.dll 4.0 and System.Web.WebPages.dll 2.0, and then referenced to web application, which runs on System.Web.Mvc.dll 5.0, compilation of web application will be correct.

#### Questions

Are there any drawbacks related to compiling a component against old System.Web.Mvc.dll 2.0, taking under consideration the fact, that such component will be then used with applications using newer versions of System.Web.Mvc.dll? What about another fact, that some types are forwarded to other library, like System.Web.WebPages.dll? Isn't it a problem here?

Maybe a better... option is just to compile this component using latest version of System.Web.Mvc.dll, and rudely ignore all the applications which uses the previous versions of MVC framework?

In general, what is the preferred way of compiling shared assemblies using some external references, while such references exists in multiple versions?

Comment: See the last section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example specified above will not work because the Type is related to assembly so since the type was moved to another assembly, it will not be find.
If in D you will reference A and B vers2 and C:
[image]
you will have exception:
[image]
If you will reference the version 1:
[image]
you will have the result (I put in output full type name and full assembly name):

```
A.TypeA|A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
A.OtherType|A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
B.OtherType|B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
C.C|C, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Maybe the solution is to compile few version of your *.dll against few versions of System.Web.Mvc.dll. Similar solution is done for x86 and x64 dlls (System.Data.SQLite.dll)
The other solution is to check by reflection in which assembly the type is and then create it on the fly using reflecion.